# Is there a way to check if a window is open in tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that'll make it so that i can pull up a window with a click of a button. I have it so that pressing `button1` will open a window called `"floor plan"` and then `button2` will open a different window called `"main menu"`. I need to be able to make it so that the user cannot keep opening duplicates of the windows. I already have

```
def floorplan():
    global floorplan
    floorplan = Toplevel()
    floorplan.title("Floor plan")
    floorplan.geometry("1366x768")
    #rest of what is needed in floorplan

def mainmenu():
    global mainmenu
    mainmenu = Toplevel()
    mainmenu.title("Main menu")
    mainmenu.geometry("1366x768")

button1=Button(root, text="floor plan", command=floorplan)
button1.place(x=10, y=10)
button2=Button(root, text="main menu", command=mainmenu)
button2.place(x=10, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

I also hope to be able to add shapes that will act like buttons, also to create new windows as well where i can manage data but that's a problem for a different day (struggling to incorporate canvas into the project but if I'm really stuck with that I'll just ask a different question).

I have tried doing checking if the button is pressed which I later realized is probably not what I want, and I have also tried checking if the window is currently active, and if it is, to ignore `button1` until the window is no longer active (and the same for `button2`) but I couldn't quite wrap my head around it. I know winfo_viewable() exists but I'm not sure how to use it. I am new to tkinter and this is a project for an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be by using flags for each window i.e. above your functions define

```
floorplan_open = False
mainmenu_open = False
```

or if you prefer working with dictionaries

```
window_states = {"floorplan_open": False, "mainmenu_open": False}
```

Then, only open a window if the corresponding variable is False.

(Remember to update the variable as True at the start of the function that opens a window, and then set it to False when the window is closed.)

Link to info about Tkinter window closing
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+protocol

Comment: This won't work well if the user closes the window. Your flag will be set but the window won't exist.

Comment: @BryanOakley Could you use `window_name.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: updating_function("floor name"))` to update the flag back to default when the user closes the window?

Comment: yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `floorplan` to `None` before `mainloop()` is called, and then check that first to see if you've created the window. Once it has been created you can use `floorplan.winfo_exists()` to determine if the window currently exists.

Also, you need to rename the `floorplan` function since the name classes with the `floorplan` variable.

```
def create_floorplan():
    global floorplan
    if floorplan is not None and floorplan.winfo_exists():
        # window has been created an exists, so don't create again.
        return

    floorplan = Toplevel()
    floorplan.title("Floor plan")
    floorplan.geometry("1366x768")
    #rest of what is needed in floorplan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also give names to your windows and check, if these names exist in a parent window (in you case it is root), you will not need to use global.

```
def floor_plan():
    if 'floorplanwindow' in root.children:
        return
    floorplan = tk.Toplevel(name='floorplanwindow')
    floorplan.title("Floor plan")
    floorplan.geometry("1366x768")


def main_menu():
    if 'mainmenuwindow' in root.children:
        return
    mainmenu = tk.Toplevel(name='mainmenuwindow')
    mainmenu.title("Main menu")
    mainmenu.geometry("1366x768")
```